# All about soundtracks and music - tag merge request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have these two tags; [music](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) and [soundtrack](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack). Music's tag wiki states:

> For questions relating to the soundtrack of a movie, use this tag for questions regarding the musical score or other music that appears in a movie.

Soundtrack's tag wiki states:

> Questions related to sound and music recorded for a motion picture or television show.

These two tags are for the same thing. Would it be possible to merge [music](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) into [soundtrack](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack), or as an alternative, synonym [music](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) to [soundtrack](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a brief overview of both tags, I don't see a reason why they shouldn't be merged.

Comment: While I generally agree with the proposal, there might still be marginal questions e.g. about the usage of certain music as a symbol or plot-element and its impact on the story while the usage of the music is rather *"in-movie"* and might not be regarded [tag:soundtrack]. But Ok, in this case [tag:music] might not be justified either, being the specific type of movie-content, for which tags are discouraged anyway.

Comment: If the question is about the use of certain music as a plot element, this would still make up part of the soundtrack of the movie.